# Matrix Optimization with vectors as variables

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, approximation, matrix-equations, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I am trying to find the encoding of each one of my samples $\vec{\phi}(x_i) \in \mathbb{R}^D$ such as it approximates $K \approx  M(\vec{\phi})$. I though this equation could work:
$$ \vec{\phi}^* = argmin_{\vec{\phi}} \lVert K - M(\vec{\phi}) \rVert $$
Where:
$$ 
K = 
\begin{bmatrix}
k(x_1-x_1) & \cdots & k(x_1-x_n) \\\\
\cdots &\cdots &\cdots\\\\ 
k(x_n-x_1) & \cdots & k(x_n-x_n) 
\end{bmatrix} 
\in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$$
$$ 
M(\vec{\phi}) = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
f(\vec{\phi}(x_1), \vec{\phi}(x_1)) & \cdots & f(\vec{\phi}(x_1), \vec{\phi}(x_n)) \\\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\\\
f(\vec{\phi}(x_n), \vec{\phi}(x_1)) & \cdots & f(\vec{\phi}(x_1), \vec{\phi}(x_1)) \end{bmatrix} 
\in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}
$$
$$ \vec{\phi} = ( \vec{\phi}(x_1), \vec{\phi}(x_2), ..., \vec{\phi}(x_n))\in \mathbb{R}^{nxD} $$
The information I have about my variables:

1. Matrix $K$ is symmetrical and uses a Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space $k(.\,.):  \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and I have all of its values.
2. Function $f(.\,.):  \mathbb{R}^D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ usually is a dot product or cosine similarity, but in this case, I want it to be any kind of function (Should I theoretically restrict them? Where can I read about this?)
3. Encoding generates an embedding $\vec{\phi}$ from an input $x_i$: [$\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^D$], where usually D >> n.

I am not sure what kind of keywords I should search for these kinds of problems, what norm I should be using, optimization methods, and increasing the efficiency of possible solutions.

Any suggestions for what should I look for will be welcome. Thank you very much!

Comment: I do not understand your first formula.

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable and the norm is euclidean, take norm squared (makes no difference for the argmin) calculate the gradient with respect to the $z_i=\phi(x_i)$ and find the zeros.

Comment: But I find your remark "what norm I should be using" strange. YOU should know the norm. If you don't care about the norm, you don't care about the result??

Comment: Yeah, I probably haven't formulated it properly but I am trying to find all the $\vec{\phi_i}$, which corresponds to the encoding of every $x_i$ that approximates the matrix $M$ as close as possible to $K$.

Comment: @g g About the norm, the problem is making both matrices as close as possible. Operator norm